# Concatenate two slices in Go

Tags: go, append, slice, variadic-functions

I'm trying to combine the slice `[1, 2]` and the slice `[3, 4]`. How can I do this in Go?

I tried:

```
append([]int{1,2}, []int{3,4})
```

but got:

```
cannot use []int literal (type []int) as type int in append
```

However, [the documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) seems to indicate this is possible, what am I missing?

```
slice = append(slice, anotherSlice...)
```

Answer (score 1493, accepted):

Add dots after the second slice:

```
//                           vvv
append([]int{1,2}, []int{3,4}...)
```

---

This is just like any other [variadic function](https://go.dev/doc/go1.17_spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters).

```
func foo(is ...int) {
    for i := 0; i < len(is); i++ {
        fmt.Println(is[i])
    }
}

func main() {
    foo([]int{9,8,7,6,5}...)
}
```

Comment: `append()` a variadic function, and the `...` lets you pass multiple arguments to a variadic function from a slice.

Comment: Is this at all performant when the slices are quite big? Or does the compiler not really pass all the elements as parameters?

Comment: @Toad: It doesn't actually spread them out. In the `foo()` example above, the `is` parameter holds a copy of the original slice, which is to say it has a copy of the light-weight reference to the same underlying array, len and cap. If the `foo` function alters a member, the change will be seen on the original. [Here's a demo](http://play.golang.org/p/JDLgYcMFFN). So the only real overhead will be that it creates a new slice if you didn't have one already, like: `foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` which will create a new slice that `is` will hold.

Comment: Ah. If I understand correctly, the variadic function is actually implemented like an array of parameters (instead of every parameter on the stack)? And since you pass in the slice, it actually maps one on one?

Comment: @Toad: Yes, when you use `...` on an existing slice, it simply passes that slice. When you pass individual arguments, it gathers them into a new slice and passes it. I don't have first-hand knowledge of the exact mechanics, but I'd guess that this: `foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and this: `func foo(is ...int) {` just de-sugars to this: `foo([]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5})` and this: `func foo(is []int) {`.

Answer (score 108):

> [Appending to and copying slices](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)
>
> The variadic function `append` appends zero or more values `x` to `s`
>   of type `S`, which must be a slice type, and returns the resulting
>   slice, also of type `S`. The values `x` are passed to a parameter of
>   type `...T` where `T` is the element type of `S` and the respective
>   parameter passing rules apply. As a special case, append also accepts
>   a first argument assignable to type `[]byte` with a second argument of
>   `string` type followed by `...`. This form appends the bytes of the
>   string.
>
> ```
> append(s S, x ...T) S  // T is the element type of S
>
> s0 := []int{0, 0}
> s1 := append(s0, 2)        // append a single element     s1 == []int{0, 0, 2}
> s2 := append(s1, 3, 5, 7)  // append multiple elements    s2 == []int{0, 0, 2, 3, 5, 7}
> s3 := append(s2, s0...)    // append a slice              s3 == []int{0, 0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 0, 0}
> ```
>
> [Passing arguments to ... parameters](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)
>
> If `f` is variadic with final parameter type `...T`, then within the
>   function the argument is equivalent to a parameter of type `[]T`. At
>   each call of `f`, the argument passed to the final parameter is a new
>   slice of type `[]T` whose successive elements are the actual arguments,
>   which all must be assignable to the type `T`. The length of the slice is
>   therefore the number of arguments bound to the final parameter and may
>   differ for each call site.

The answer to your question is example `s3 := append(s2, s0...)` in the [Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec). For example,

```
s := append([]int{1, 2}, []int{3, 4}...)
```

Comment: Note: general use of append(slice1, slice2...) seems quite dangerous to me. If slice1 is a slice of a larger array, values of that array will get overwritten by slice2. (It makes me cringe that this doesn't seem to be a common concern?)

Comment: @Hugo If you "hand" over a slice of your array, then know that the slice "owner" will be able to see/overwrite parts of the array that are beyond the current length of the slice. If you don't want this, you may use a [full slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) (in the form of `a[low : high : max]`) which also specifies the maximum _capacity_. For example the slice `a[0:2:4]` will have a capacity of `4` and it cannot be resliced to include elements beyond that, not even if the backing array has a thousand elements after that.

Answer (score 74):

I would like to emphasize @icza answer and simplify it a bit since it is a crucial concept. I assume that reader is familiar with [slices](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals).

```
c := append(a, b...)
```

This is a valid answer to the question. 
**BUT if you need to use slices 'a' and 'c' later in code in different context, this is not the safe way to concatenate slices.**

To explain, lets read the expression not in terms of slices, but in terms of underlying arrays:

> "Take (underlying) array of 'a' and append elements from array 'b' to
>   it. If array 'a' has enough capacity to include all elements from 'b'
>   - underlying array of 'c' will not be a new array, it will actually be array 'a'. Basically, slice 'a' will show len(a) elements of
>   underlying array 'a', and slice 'c' will show len(c) of array 'a'."

append() does not necessarily create a new array! This can lead to unexpected results. See [Go Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/jB67vYztD-3).

**Always use make() function if you want to make sure that new array is allocated for the slice. For example here are few ugly but efficient enough options for the task.**

```
la := len(a)
c := make([]int, la, la + len(b))
_ = copy(c, a)
c = append(c, b...)
```

---

```
la := len(a)
c := make([]int, la + len(b))
_ = copy(c, a)
_ = copy(c[la:], b)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to these side effects. Amazingly contrasting to to this modified szenario. https://play.golang.org/p/9FKo5idLBj4 Though when providing excess capacity, one should carefully thinking about these puzzling sideeffects against 
plausible intuition.

Comment: Thanks Joo, i spend almost two hours lokking for a problem in the code that whas because i didn't follow the guileline you stated about not beign safe to concatenate two slices that you will use later (maybe the could include on this doc that warning: https://blog.golang.org/slices). And thanks for the copy snippet it looks very tastefull!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Remember, always save append's output to the same variable as the first argument, like so: `a := append(a, b...)`

Answer (score 57):

Nothing against the other answers, but I found the brief explanation in [the docs](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) more easily understandable than the examples in them:

> ### func append
>
> `func append(slice []Type, elems ...Type) []Type` The append built-in
>   function appends elements to the end of a slice. If it has sufficient
>   capacity, the destination is resliced to accommodate the new elements.
>   If it does not, a new underlying array will be allocated. Append
>   returns the updated slice. It is therefore necessary to store the
>   result of append, often in the variable holding the slice itself:
>
> ```
> slice = append(slice, elem1, elem2)
> slice = append(slice, anotherSlice...)
> ```
>
> As a special case, it is legal to append a string to a byte slice,
>   like this:
>
> ```
> slice = append([]byte("hello "), "world"...)
> ```

Comment: Thank you! Valuable for me!

Comment: Wish this was the top answer!

Answer (score 39):

I think it's important to point out and to know that if the destination slice (the slice you append to) has sufficient capacity, the append will happen "in-place", by reslicing the destination (reslicing to *increase* its length in order to be able to accommodate the appendable elements).

This means that if the destination was created by slicing a bigger array or slice which has additional elements beyond the length of the resulting slice, they may get overwritten.

To demonstrate, see this example:

```
a := [10]int{1, 2}
fmt.Printf("a: %v\n", a)

x, y := a[:2], []int{3, 4}
fmt.Printf("x: %v, y: %v\n", x, y)
fmt.Printf("cap(x): %v\n", cap(x))

x = append(x, y...)
fmt.Printf("x: %v\n", x)

fmt.Printf("a: %v\n", a)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/EVcatuZhki)):

```
a: [1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
x: [1 2], y: [3 4]
cap(x): 10
x: [1 2 3 4]
a: [1 2 3 4 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

We created a "backing" array `a` with length `10`. Then we create the `x` destination slice by slicing this `a` array, `y` slice is created using the composite literal `[]int{3, 4}`. Now when we append `y` to `x`, the result is the expected `[1 2 3 4]`, but what may be surprising is that the backing array `a` also changed, because capacity of `x` is `10` which is sufficient to append `y` to it, so `x` is resliced which will also use the same `a` backing array, and `append()` will copy elements of `y` into there.

If you want to avoid this, you may use a [full slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) which has the form

```
a[low : high : max]
```

which constructs a slice and also controls the resulting slice's capacity by setting it to `max - low`.

See the modified example (the only difference is that we create `x` like this: `x = a[:2:2]`:

```
a := [10]int{1, 2}
fmt.Printf("a: %v\n", a)

x, y := a[:2:2], []int{3, 4}
fmt.Printf("x: %v, y: %v\n", x, y)
fmt.Printf("cap(x): %v\n", cap(x))

x = append(x, y...)
fmt.Printf("x: %v\n", x)

fmt.Printf("a: %v\n", a)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/e1mvWOc8_Q))

```
a: [1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
x: [1 2], y: [3 4]
cap(x): 2
x: [1 2 3 4]
a: [1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

As you can see, we get the same `x` result but the backing array `a` did not change, because capacity of `x` was "only" `2` (thanks to the full slice expression `a[:2:2]`). So to do the append, a new backing array is allocated that can store the elements of both `x` and `y`, which is distinct from `a`.

Comment: It's very helpful to the problem I'm facing. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, very useful - however, will the behavior illustrated *only* happen if the backing array is short enough to fit the new values in? E.g if in your example `y` was length 20, would the `a` remain unchanged?

Comment: @patrick Yes, if there's not enough room to append, `append()` allocates a new backing array, copies the old content over, and performs the append on the new backing array and leaves the old one intact. How hard it is to try? [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/w9-Wt2EClGO)

Answer (score 9):

### append( ) function and spread operator

Two slices can be concatenated using **`append`** method in the standard golang library. Which is similar to the `variadic` function operation. So we need to use `...`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    x := []int{1, 2, 3}
    y := []int{4, 5, 6}
    z := append([]int{}, append(x, y...)...)
    fmt.Println(z)
}
```

> output of the above code is:  [1 2 3 4 5 6]

Comment: I'm not sure why you just don't use `z := append(x, y...)`.

Answer (score 7):

To concatenate two slices,

```
func main() {
    s1 := []int{1, 2, 3}
    s2 := []int{99, 100}
    s1 = append(s1, s2...)

    fmt.Println(s1) // [1 2 3 99 100]
}
```

To append a single value to a slice

```
func main() {
    s1 :=  []int{1,2,3}
    s1 := append(s1, 4)
    
    fmt.Println(s1) // [1 2 3 4]
}
```

To append multiple values to a slice

```
func main() {
    s1 :=  []int{1,2,3}
    s1 = append(s1, 4, 5)
    
    fmt.Println(s1) // [1 2 3 4]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Seems like a perfect use for generics (if using 1.18 or later).

```golang
func concat[T any](first []T, second []T) []T {
    n := len(first);
    return append(first[:n:n], second...);
}
```

Comment: append is already "generic" so one could think this isn't a necessary use case for type parameters, **but** the non-obvious usage of the three-index slice expression `:n:n` to cut the capacity of the first slice is a definite improvement

Answer (score 4):

With Go 1.22 (Q1 2024), you might consider the new `func Concat[S ~[]E, E any](slices ...S) S` generic function.

See [commit 2fd195](https://github.com/fancybits/go/commit/2fd19511a32cfbc6465c968ee02dd0001da31a68), which fixes [issue 56353](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/56353)

```golang
// Join slices into a new slice
a := []int{ 1, 2, 3 }
b := []int{ 4, 5, 6 }
c := slices.Concat(nil, a, b) 
// c == int{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }

s := [][]int{{1}, nil, {2}}
c = slices.Concat(s...)
// c == int{1, 2}
```

This is being followed with ["New API changes for Go 1.22" (issue 64343)](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/64343).

Answer (score 3):

`append([]int{1,2}, []int{3,4}...)` will work. Passing arguments to `...` parameters.

If `f` is variadic with a final parameter `p` of type `...T`, then within `f` the type of `p` is equivalent to type `[]T`.

If `f` is invoked with no actual arguments for `p`, the value passed to `p` is `nil`.

Otherwise, the value passed is a new slice of type `[]T` with a new underlying array whose successive elements are the actual arguments, which all must be assignable to `T`. The length and capacity of the slice is therefore the number of arguments bound to `p` and may differ for each call site.

Given the function and calls

```
func Greeting(prefix string, who ...string)
Greeting("nobody")
Greeting("hello:", "Joe", "Anna", "Eileen")
```