# Concat multiple slices in golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to merge multiple slices as follows,

```
package routes

import (
    "net/http"
)

type Route struct {
    Name        string
    Method      string
    Pattern     string
    Secured     bool
    HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
}

type Routes []Route

var ApplicationRoutes Routes

func init() {
    ApplicationRoutes = append(
        WifiUserRoutes,
        WifiUsageRoutes,
        WifiLocationRoutes,
        DashboardUserRoutes,
        DashoardAppRoutes,
        RadiusRoutes,
        AuthenticationRoutes...
    )
}
```

However the builtin append() is capable of appending two slices, hence it throws **too many arguments to append** at compile time. Is there an alternative function to achieve the task? or is there a better way to merge the slices?

Comment: The Go 1.22 (Q1 2024) [`slices.Concat` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77562293/6309) should help.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`append` operates on individual elements, not on entire slices. Append each slice in a loop

```
routes := []Routes{
    WifiUserRoutes,
    WifiUsageRoutes,
    WifiLocationRoutes,
    DashboardUserRoutes,
    DashoardAppRoutes,
    RadiusRoutes,
    AuthenticationRoutes,
}

var ApplicationRoutes []Route
for _, r := range routes {
    ApplicationRoutes = append(ApplicationRoutes, r...)
}
```

Answer (score 44):

This question has been answered already, but I wanted to post this here because the accepted answer is not the most efficient.

The reason is that creating an empty slice and then appending can lead to many unnecessary allocations.

The most efficient way would be to pre-allocate a slice and copy the elements into it. Below is a package which implements the concatenation both ways. If you benchmark you can see that pre-allocating is ~2x faster and allocates much less memory.

Benchmark Results:

```
go test . -bench=. -benchmem
testing: warning: no tests to run
BenchmarkConcatCopyPreAllocate-8    30000000            47.9 ns/op        64 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkConcatAppend-8             20000000           107 ns/op         112 B/op          3 allocs/op
```

Package concat:

```
package concat

func concatCopyPreAllocate(slices [][]byte) []byte {
    var totalLen int
    for _, s := range slices {
        totalLen += len(s)
    }
    tmp := make([]byte, totalLen)
    var i int
    for _, s := range slices {
        i += copy(tmp[i:], s)
    }
    return tmp
}

func concatAppend(slices [][]byte) []byte {
    var tmp []byte
    for _, s := range slices {
        tmp = append(tmp, s...)
    }
    return tmp
}
```

Benchmark tests:

```
package concat

import "testing"

var slices = [][]byte{
    []byte("my first slice"),
    []byte("second slice"),
    []byte("third slice"),
    []byte("fourth slice"),
    []byte("fifth slice"),
}

var B []byte

func BenchmarkConcatCopyPreAllocate(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        B = concatCopyPreAllocate(slices)
    }
}

func BenchmarkConcatAppend(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        B = concatAppend(slices)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/slices also seems to support this being the more efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

#### Go 1.22

Use [`slices.Concat`](https://pkg.go.dev/slices#Concat). The signature is variadic, so you can call it with how many slices (of the same type) you want:

```
func main() {
    s1 := []int{1, 2}
    s2 := []int{3, 4}
    s3 := []int{5, 6}

    s := slices.Concat(s1, s2, s3)
    fmt.Println(s) // [1 2 3 4 5 6]
    fmt.Println("len:", len(s)) // len: 6
    fmt.Println("cap:", cap(s)) // cap: 6
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/rF623N2Npzk

Under the hood, this function calls [`slices.Grow`](https://pkg.go.dev/slices#Grow) to set the capacity of the resulting slice to exactly what's needed to accommodate all the elements without more allocations than necessary.

Answer (score -1):

2023 Update:

As of go 1.22, the standard library contains a slices package with a Concat function.

https://pkg.go.dev/slices@master#Concat