# Concatenate 2 slices in golang

Tags: go, slice

I have 2 slices,

```
s1 := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
s2 := []int{3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

I want the resultant

```
s3 = []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

I am doing something like:

```
for _, x := range s1 {
        s2 = append(s2, x)
    }
```

This looks very trivial question but trust me I don't find a one line solution to this. 
How can we go about this?

Comment: The Go 1.22 (Q1 2024) [`slices.Concat` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77562293/6309) should help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is what the builtin [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) function is for: to append values (which may be values of a slice) to the end of another. And the result is the concatenation.

If you want `s3` to be "independent" of `s1` and `s2`, then append `s1` to an empty or `nil` slice, then append `s2` to the result:

```
s3 := append(append([]int{}, s1...), s2...)
fmt.Println(s3)
```

If `s3` may use / overlap `s1`, you can simply append `s2` to `s1`:

```
s4 := append(s1, s2...)
fmt.Println(s4)
```

Output in both cases (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IraYWETFl-)):

```
[1 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6 7]
```

Note: What this "overlapping" means is that if you append values to `s1`, if it has enough capacity, no new slice will be allocated, `s1` will be resliced to have enough length to accommodate the elements you want to append to it. This may have surprising side-effects if used unwisely, like in this example:

```
arr := [...]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0}

s1 := arr[:5]
s2 := arr[2:7]
fmt.Println("s1:", s1, "cap:", cap(s1))
fmt.Println("s2:", s2)

s3 := append(s1, s2...)
fmt.Println("s3:", s3)

fmt.Println("s2:", s2)
```

Output is (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cKLTBZRcT2)):

```
s1: [1 2 3 4 5] cap: 10
s2: [3 4 5 6 7]
s3: [1 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6 7]
s2: [3 4 5 3 4]
```

What may be surprising here is that when we appended `s2` to `s1` and stored the result in `s3` (which is what we expected), contents (elements) of `s2` also changed. The reason for this is that `append()` saw that `s1` has enough capacity to append `s2` to it (elements of `s2`), so it did not create a new array, it just resliced `s1` and added elements "in-place". But the area where the additional elements were written is the exact same memory where elements of `s2` reside, so elements of `s2` also got overwritten.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to give a look at this page: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks

It's an official documentation by golang for slices. For your problem you just need to use `append` :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Go 1.22

You can use [`slices.Concat`](https://pkg.go.dev/slices#Concat) from the standard library:

```
func main() {
    s1 := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    s2 := []int{6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    
    s := slices.Concat(s1, s2) 
    fmt.Println(s) // [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/mXKIoKO1J_b

In my personal opinion this looks nicer than `append` with the spread syntax `...`. Anyway, the actual implementation under the hood still uses just that, so you don't have to.