# Golang create array from values present in all arrays

Tags: go

I need to create an array from multiple arrays. The new array must only contain the values that is present in all arrays passed in. For example.

```
array1 := []string{"hello", "germany", "brasil", "fiji"}
array2 := []string{"goodbye", "germany", "brasil", "fiji"}
array3 := []string{"hello", "brasil", "fiji"}
array4 := []string{"hello", "brasil", "fiji", "usa"}

func mergeArrays(arrs ...[]string) []string{
   // process arrays
}

myNewArray := mergeArrays(array1,array2,array3,array4)
fmt.Println(myNewArray) // ["fiji", "brasil"]
```

The example should return `["fiji", "brasil"]` since they are the only values present in all arrays.

How could I go about writing a function that could achieve such a goal in golang?

This is my attempt but feels a bit clumsy

```
func mergeArrays(arrs ...[]string) []string {
    var finalArr []string
    if len(arrs) == 0 {
        return finalArr
    }

    for i, a := range arrs {
        if i == 0 {
            finalArr = arrs[0]
            continue
        }
        for i, e := range finalArr {
            if !strContains(a, e) {
                finalArr = append(finalArr[:i], finalArr[i+1:]...)
            }
        }

    }

    return finalArr
}

func strContains(s []string, e string) bool {
    for _, a := range s {
        if a == e {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/KRygw7OVBbn

Comment: Have you tried at all? Can you should what you've tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate two slices in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248241/concatenate-two-slices-in-go)

Comment: @Adrian update the question to show the work I've tried

Comment: @g4s8 I think my use case is a bit different

Comment: @user10457989: Do you care about order?

Comment: @TimCooper Nope

Comment: Use a go `map` to track unique entries. Populate a "master" map with the first slice (note I used the term *slice* not array - as arrays have fixed immutable sizes - you are using slices). Then iterate the remaining slices, creating an individual map based on that slice. With this iterate the master-map removing any keys from the master that are not in this individual map. Rince & Repeat. Finally output a slice of the remaining master-map keys - that will be your set of words common to all slices.

Comment: @colminator would you mind showing an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per my comment above, here's one way to do it with go `map`s and thus avoid iterating over potentially large slices:

```
func itemize(a []string) map[string]struct{} {
    m := make(map[string]struct{})
    for _, v:=range a {
        m[v] = struct{}{} // struct{}{} == an empty struct (i.e. a value that incurs no storage)
    }
    return m
}

func commonElements(arrs ...[]string) (results []string) {
    if len(arrs) == 0 {
        return // edge case
    }

    mm := itemize(arrs[0]) // master map

    for i:=1; i<len(arrs);i++ {
        m := itemize(arrs[i]) // current map
        for k := range mm {
            if _, ok := m[k]; !ok {
                delete(mm, k) // master item not in current slice, so remove from master
            }
        }
    }

    results = make([]string, len(mm)) // make a precisely sized slice...
    i:=0
    for k := range mm {
        results[i] = k // so we can insert results directly into it without using append
        i++ 
    }

    return
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/pTaXR-nY9zm

Answer (score 0):

Idea:

1. Count number of appearances of each item across arrays(`arr`).
2. If that number is exactly same as `len(arr)`, the item presents in all arrays.

Here's an example that employees this approach:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func uniq(arr []string) []string {
    cache := make(map[string]struct{})
    for _, s := range arr {
        cache[s] = struct{}{}
    }
    var r []string
    for s := range cache {
        r = append(r, s)
    }
    return r
}

func mergeArrays(arrs ...[]string) []string {
    count := make(map[string]int)
    for _, arr := range arrs {
        for _, s := range uniq(arr) {
            count[s]++
        }
    }
    var merged []string
    for s, n := range count {
        if n == len(arrs) {
            merged = append(merged, s)
        }
    }
    return merged
}

func main() {
    array1 := []string{"hello", "germany", "brasil", "fiji"}
    array2 := []string{"goodbye", "germany", "brasil", "fiji"}
    array3 := []string{"hello", "brasil", "fiji"}
    array4 := []string{"hello", "brasil", "fiji", "usa"}

    myNewArray := mergeArrays(array1, array2, array3, array4)
    fmt.Println(myNewArray) // ["fiji", "brasil"]
}
```

And playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/FB3wJ7-gaIa

**EDIT**: it will work properly even if there's any duplicate in each array.

Answer (score 0):

@colminator's is a valid answer but the algorithm is not optimal. @hallazang's suggestion is a right approach, but why creating 2 maps if we need only one? See the next option for better efficiency.

```
func repeatingItemsFromArrays(arrays ...[]string) []string {
    la := len(arrays)
    out := []string{}

    // handle corner cases for efficiency
    if la == 0 {
        return out
    }
    if la == 1 {
        return arrays[0]
    }

    m := make(map[string]int)

    for i := range arrays {
        for j := range arrays[i] {
            m[arrays[i][j]]++
        }
    }

    for k, v := range m {
        if v == la {
            out = append(out, k)
        }
    }

    return out
}
```