# Calculating sha256 gives different results after appending slices depending on if I print out the slice before or not

Tags: go, slice, sha256

I am calculating a sha256 from multiple strings. I convert them to byte slices in a specific way and append them all together and then compute the hash using the built in library. However, depending on if I print out the slice before calculating the sha256 or not I wierdly get different results. When testing it in playground I cannot reproduce it.

The tested code can been seen and run on https://play.golang.org/p/z8XKx-p9huG where it actually gives the same result in both cases.

```
func getHash(input1 string, input2hex string, input3hex string, input4 string) (string, error) {
    input1bytes := []byte(input1)
    firstHalfinput1Bytes := input1bytes[:8]
    secondHalfinput1Bytes := input1bytes[8:16]

    input4Bytes := []byte(input4)

    input3Bytes, err := hex.DecodeString(input3hex)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err " + err.Error())
    }

    input2Bytes, err := hex.DecodeString(input2hex)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err " + err.Error())
    }

    fullHashInputBytes := append(firstHalfinput1Bytes, input2Bytes...)
    // THIS IS THE OPTIONAL PRINT WHICH CHANGES OUTPUT LOCALLY:
    fmt.Println("fullHashInputBytes", fullHashInputBytes)
    fullHashInputBytes = append(fullHashInputBytes, secondHalfinput1Bytes...)
    fullHashInputBytes = append(fullHashInputBytes, input3Bytes...)
    fullHashInputBytes = append(fullHashInputBytes, input4Bytes...)
    sha256 := sha256.Sum256(fullHashInputBytes)
    for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
        sha256[i+16] ^= sha256[i+24]
    }
    hash := hex.EncodeToString(sha256[:24])
    fmt.Println("hash", hash)
    return hash, nil
}
```

The logs on the playground are

```
Hello, playground
fullHashInputBytes [84 72 73 83 73 83 78 79 30 0 22 121 57 203 102 148 210 196 34 172 210 8 160 7]
hash 0161d9de8dd815ca9f4e1c7bb8684562542cc24b1026321c
hash 0161d9de8dd815ca9f4e1c7bb8684562542cc24b1026321c
```

but if I run EXACTLY the same code locally (just copy-paste it into a main.go and do `go run main.go` or `go build .` and `./test`) I get

```
Hello, playground
fullHashInputBytes [84 72 73 83 73 83 78 79 30 0 22 121 57 203 102 148 210 196 34 172 210 8 160 7]
hash 0161d9de8dd815ca9f4e1c7bb8684562542cc24b1026321c
hash d2de4ffb4e8790b8fd1ceeba726436fd97875a5740c27b47
```

I'm using go version `1.13.4` but had the same issue with `1.10.4`. I also get the same issue on both my local machine and when deployed to our server.

Comment: Your question is a little "busy" - so let me ask, is there any buffering (e.g. `bytes.Buffer`) used when relaying data to the hasher? If so, ensure the final write is flushed to ensure you're hashing the entire payload.

Comment: The code is exactly what you see, no buffers. I test it with hardcoded strings (see the playground link). But perhaps I could remove almost all of the question and just referr to the playground link to make it more digestible :)

Comment: Removed most of the text and referr to the link instead so hopefully it's less busy!

Comment: Questions should include relevant code *in the body of the question*, not just at an external link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you create `fullHashInputBytes` by appending to `firstHalfinput1Bytes` first:

```
fullHashInputBytes := append(firstHalfinput1Bytes, input2Bytes...)
```

Which is a slice of the `input1bytes`:

```
firstHalfinput1Bytes := input1bytes[:8]
```

So the first append may overwrite the contents of `input1bytes` at indices higher than 7, which is actually the content of `secondHalfinput1Bytes`:

```
secondHalfinput1Bytes := input1bytes[8:16]
```

So later when you also append `secondHalfinput1Bytes` to `fullHashInputBytes`, you might end up appending different contents.

This is most likely not what you want.

If you do it "clean":

```
var fullHashInputBytes []byte
fullHashInputBytes = append(fullHashInputBytes, firstHalfinput1Bytes...)
fullHashInputBytes = append(fullHashInputBytes, input2Bytes...)
// OPTIONAL print doesn't change anything:
fmt.Println("fullHashInputBytes", fullHashInputBytes)
// ...rest of your appends...
```

Then output will be the same if you run it locally or on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2LUP6lavyhj).

### Why the deviant behavior?

Whether your first append overwrites `input1bytes` depends on whether the append can be performed "in-place", without having to allocate a new backing array, which depends on the capacity of `firstHalfinput1Bytes`, which is "inherited" from `input1bytes`:

```
input1bytes := []byte(input1)
fmt.Println(cap(input1bytes))
```

(You may read about it in greater detail here: [Concatenate two slices in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248241/concatenate-two-slices-in-go/40036950#40036950)).

The [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) `[]byte(input)` only guarantees to have the bytes of `input1`, but the spec does not dictate how big the capacity of the resulting slice should be. And it may depend on platform / architecture. On the Go Playground the above conversion results in `capacity = 16`, on my local `amd64` architecture I get `capacity = 32`.

One final piece: the capacity used for the slice of the result of the `[]byte(input)` conversion may depend on what you do with the result slice. The compiler may make decisions to use lower capacity if you pass it to `fmt.Println()` as this signals that the slice may escape. Again, the decision made by the compiler is out of your hands.

Don't rely on such thing, do not write code that relies on the capacity of the resulting slice of a conversion. Do it in the "clean" way: do not append to `firstHalfinput1Bytes` but to a new slice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, makes sense! I ended up making the slice with its finally capacity and copying in the content of the other slices instead but good to know this anyway! A funny thing is that we have an almost identical functionality in another service (slight difference in the actual content and do one more append at the end, maybe that one has an impact on the final capacity or something) where I also make this mistake but that one has always given the correct expected checksum ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @poppe Don't temp the devil, do not rely on the capacity which is not specified by the language spec. If you do so, your code might give wrong results with the next version of Go.

Comment: @izca If you're referring to the other service that makes the same mistake we're just now fixing it so it also does it the proper way :)

Comment: @poppe Yes, I was referring to that.