# Adding 2 array `type`s in Golang

Tags: arrays, go, struct

I have a `type` called `EmployeeList` which is just an array of `Employee` structs.

If I have to add/combine `EmployeeList` objects, I thought I could add them as follows

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

type Employee struct {
  Id      int    `json:"id"`
  Name string    `json:"name"`
}

type EmployeeList []Employee

func main() {
  listA := EmployeeList{
    Employee{Id: 1, Name: "foo"},
    Employee{Id: 2, Name: "bar"},
  }

  listB := EmployeeList{
    Employee{Id: 3, Name: "baz"},
  }

  // Print the combined lists
  fmt.Println(append(listA, listB))
}
```

However the `append` is throwing an error:

```
./prog.go:24:21: cannot use listB (type EmployeeList) as type Employee in append
```

I get that it has to do with a mismatched / unexpected type, but I'm not sure how to add these two lists together?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `append(listA, listB...)`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot append an `EmployeeList` to an array of `Employee`. But because `EmployeeList` is defined as a list of `Employee`, you can unpack that array and append its elements to `listA`. You can unpack the array with `...`.

```
append(listA, listB...)
```

(refer to a similar answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16248257/5666087)

Comment: That makes sense. Very similar to the splat operator `*args` in ruby I guess. Thank you!