# creating new slice by appending to existing slice in golang

Tags: go, slice, permutation

I am writing a program to generate all possible permutations of a slice of unique elements.
The code for the same can be found [here](https://play.golang.org/p/C7Kbiq6ajlt)

At one point I need to create a new slice from the original slice of numbers. This new slice has one less element than the original slice. I tried two different variants with `append`

`nums` is the original slice and `remaining` is the new slice I am trying to create.
`i` is an `int` which can range from `0` to `len(nums)-1`.

Variant 1:

```
remaining := make([]int, 0)
remaining = append(remaining, nums[:i]...)
remaining = append(remaining, nums[i+1:]...)
```

Variant 2:

```
remaining := append(nums[:i], nums[i+1:]...)
```

While the program works fine with Variant 1 , it  doesn't behave correctly with Variant 2.
I want to understand what is the exact difference in these two Variants ?

Comment: You are using slice having same array backing, means `nums` also modified see [here](https://play.golang.org/p/cAwYaFJDxuC)

Comment: I recommend you explore [slices-intro](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro)

Comment: neither `nums` nor `remaining` is ever mutated? What exactly is causing the modification?

Comment: See this answer: [Concatenate two slices in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248241/concatenate-two-slices-in-go/40036950?r=SearchResults#40036950).

Comment: You are appending in nums so "1 2 3" became "2 3 3"

Comment: Do not use `append` to create a new slice, use it to append to a slice. To create a new slice, use a slice literal or `make()`. To copy data from an existing slice to the new slice, use `copy()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here slice `nums[:i]` is created by slicing a bigger array `nums`. This leads to it having enough capacity to extend in place. So an operation like  `append(nums[:i], nums[i+1:]...)` causes the elements in `nums` getting overridden by elements from `nums[i+1:]`. This mutates the original array and hence the behaviour.

As suggested by @icza the concept has been capture [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248241/concatenate-two-slices-in-go/40036950#40036950).

To fix the Variant 2 we can use [full slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) like this

```
remaining := append(nums[0:i:i], nums[i+1:len(nums):len(nums)]...)
```