# Merge pointer to a slice

Tags: go

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mfLDZ1Z9HJZ)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func randoms() *[]int {
  var nums []int = make([]int, 5, 5) //Created slice with fixed Len, cap
  fmt.Println(len(nums))
  for i := range [5]int{} {//Added random numbers.
     nums[i] = rand.Intn(10)
  }
  return &nums//Returning pointer to the slice
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    var nums []int = make([]int, 0, 25)
    for _ = range [5]int{} {//Calling the functions 5 times
       res := randoms() 
       fmt.Println(res)
       //nums = append(nums, res)
       for _, i := range *res {//Iterating and appending them
         nums = append(nums, i)
       }
    }
    fmt.Println(nums)
}
```

I am trying to mimic my problem. I have dynamic number of function calls i.e `randoms` and dynamic number of results. I need to append all of the results i.e `numbers in this case`.

I am able to do this with `iteration` and no issues with it. I am looking for a way to do something like `nums = append(nums, res)`. Is there any way to do this/any built-in methods/did I misunderstand the pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `append(nums, (*res)...)`:

```golang
       nums = append(nums, (*res)...)
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/kkBGzhCpKcN)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16248257/13860) for more about `...`, but in short it expands the contents of a slice. Example:

```golang
x := []int{1, 2, 3}
y := []int{4, 5, 6}
x = append(x, y...) // Now x = []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

Further, since you have a pointer to a slice, you need to dereference the pointer with `*`.

```golang
x := []int{1, 2, 3}
y := &x
x = append(x, (*x)...) // x = []int{1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}
```